# Visual Studio 2013, the simplest program and weir behavior

Tags: visual-studio

So I got pretty confused and I have no idea what to even google. Basically, I recently installed Visual Studio 2013(I also have atmel studio 7, which is an IDE based on visual also), and the instalation seems corrupted to me..

I created a simple project named 'test', here's source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    printf("xxxx");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In linker settings i set system to console. And when I run it, here's what I get:
[image: a busy cat]

So the terminal opens up and shows nothing, and the task manager sees 3 processes of my app.

What is it about? I tried 'repairing' the instalation of Visual Studio, didn't do much. I'm really confused with that..

Comment: Are you sure all three instances came from launching your program once? Or are they never exiting?

Comment: Okay, this is weird. After repairing the VS i rebooted the computer, ran the IDE and launched the application once-I got the results I posted, 3 processes. But now, after another reboot I saw only one process running.. Let's assume that it doesn't create redundant processes, still-why don't I see anything in the console? Also the processes remain after closing the terminal, and are invincible, can't kill them with task manager. Why might this happen?

Comment: Are you trying to write C or C++? I don't know for sure that `system("pause")` is the issue, but when I make a "hello world" application I'd usually include `<iostream>` and instead of print/pause, do `std::cout << "xxx" << std::endl; std::cin.ignore(); return 0;`

Comment: Uninstall Avast asap.

Comment: NicolasHolthaus: Well that didn't look like a solution, but still tried it out-nopes. :D My code is a valid c code, so it should work, and now it does.

@HansPassant Wow, impressive clairvoyance skills! Haha indeed I use avast and after I shut it down, the app started to work. Thanks alot, man!